# Adding two array objects together

Tags: java, math, arraylist, binary

I'm trying to add two DNumber objects in the add(DNumber b) method. The point is to be able to do binary arithmetic. The elements are stored normally. How should I handle ArrayLists that are not even? Fill the one with fewer elements with 0s?. Then how should I retrieve each element? Also what would be a good way to convert to decimal without using the convert to decimal method:

```
public class DNumber{
    ArrayList<Digit> binary = new ArrayList<Digit>();
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class DNumber
     */
    public DNumber()
    {
        Digit num = new Digit(0);
        binary.add(num);
    }

    public DNumber(int val){
        int num = val;
        if(num > 0){
            while (num > 0){
                Digit bin = new Digit(num%2);
                num /= 2;
                binary.add(0, bin);
            }
        }
        else{
            Digit bin = new Digit(0);
            binary.add(0,bin);
        }
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public String toString(){
        String s = "";
        for(Digit d : binary){
            s = s + d.toString();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void add(DNumber b){
        int ArraySize1 = binary.size() -1;
        int ArraySize2 = b.binary.size() -1;


    }

    public void toDecimal(){
        /**
         *
         *  String s = "";
         int result = 0;
         int power = 0;
         for(Digit d : binary){
         s = s + d.toString();
         result = Integer.parseInt(s);
         }
         */
    }
}

public class Digit {
    int x = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Digit
     */
    public Digit(int val) {
        if (val != 0 && val != 1) {
            System.out.println("Error Must be either 1 or 0");
            x = 0;
        } else {
            x = val;
        }
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param y a sample parameter for a method
     * @return the sum of x and y
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setValue(int num) {
        if (num != 0 && num != 1) {
            System.out.println("Error Must be either 1 or 0");
            System.out.println("Old Value Retained");
        } else {
            x = num;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(x);
    }

    public Digit add(Digit b) {
        int returnInt = getValue() + b.getValue();
        Digit carry = new Digit(0);
        if (returnInt == 2) {
            carry = new Digit(1);
            setValue(0);
        } else if (returnInt == 1) {
            carry = new Digit(0);
            setValue(1);
        } else if (returnInt == 0) {
            carry = new Digit(0);
            setValue(0);
        }
        return carry;
    }

    public Digit add(Digit b, Digit c) {
        int returnInt = getValue() + b.getValue() + c.getValue();
        Digit carry = new Digit(0);
        if (returnInt == 2) {
            carry = new Digit(1);
            setValue(0);
        } else if (returnInt == 1) {
            carry = new Digit(0);
            setValue(1);
        } else if (returnInt == 0) {
            carry = new Digit(0);
            setValue(0);
        } else if (returnInt == 3) {
            carry = new Digit(1);
            setValue(1);
        }
        return carry;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad thing to have a Digit class to force the 1s and 0s, but having an add method on the Digit class doesn't make a lot of sense as you're not really able to handle the carry bit. I would focus on just handling add at the DNumber level and making the 0th element the 0 bit will likely make things easier

Answer (score 0):

Consider this small change to your constructor.

```
while (num > 0){
    Digit bin = new Digit(num%2);
    num /= 2;
    binary.add(bin);
}
```

This might seem strange at first, new DNumber(6) gives you a list (0,1,1) which seems backwards, but is much easier to work with.

You can easily convert this to a decimal:

```
    public int toDecimal() {
        int total = 0;
        int power = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.size(); i++) {
            total += binary.get(i).getValue() * power;
            power *= 2;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

When it comes to adding you start at the 0th element with a carry of 0, if one array is longer than the other it's much easier to handle.

Consider adding 6 and 4

```
carry = 0
a = (0,1,1)
b = (0,0,1)
answer = ()
```

at start, it's 0+0+0 = 0, carry 0

```
carry=0
a = (1,1)
b = (0,1)
answer = (0)
```

the next interation, it's 0+1+0 = 1, carry 0

```
carry=0
a = (1)
b = (1)
answer = (0,1)
```

the next iteration, it's 0+1+1 = 0, carry 1

```
carry=1
a = ()
b = ()
answer = (0,1,0)
```

The next iteration both input lists are empty, so we just add the carry bit

answer = (0,1,0,1) which if you run through toDecimal is 10